# How to put tabs inside a scrollview in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So basically I am very new to SwiftUI(started a few days ago) and am trying to put tabs within a `ScrollView`. The end result I am trying to achieve is that of Instagram's profile view.

I'd imagine the view's implementation would be something like this:

```
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                // Profile Pic
                // Stats
            }
            // Bio
            // Button(s)
            LazyVStack(pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                Section {
                    TabView {
                        // Tab 1
                        // Tab 2
                        // Tab 3
                    }
                } headers: {
                      // Tab icons
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, the TabView never appears. Also I am unsure whether this is the best setup especially the `LazyVStack` as I am only using to for the fact that it pins the headers. As I said previously, I'm super new to SwiftUI so there are definetly some views that I have no idea exist some of which might be useful in what I am trying to achieve.

Nonetheless, how can I achieve the layout I am going for?

Thank you!

**Side Question:** With the way that I have the view setup, the scrollbar for the view is for the entire view however in apps like Instagram, the scrollbars are only within the tabs themselves. How could I also incorporate that aspect into the solution? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. `TabView` when not used as the root loses the ability to resize it self properly.

So that's why we need to specfiy its `minHeight`. You can use `GeometryReader` for that.

Then just give `TabView` a `selection` in order for the Tab-Buttons to work and most likely you want to apply `.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))` in order to be able to swipe between them.

Working Demo:

```swift
GeometryReader { proxy in
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                Text("Some Text")
            }
        }
        
        LazyVStack(spacing: 0, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
            Section {
                TabView(selection: $tabIndex) {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("1")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.red.opacity(0.5))
                    .tag(0)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("2")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.green.opacity(0.5))
                    .tag(1)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("3")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.blue.opacity(0.5))
                    .tag(2)
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: proxy.size.height)
            } header: {
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            tabIndex = 0
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Tab 1")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            tabIndex = 1
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Tab 2")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                    
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            tabIndex = 2
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Tab 3")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                }
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.regularMaterial)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As to your side question: They most likely still use a single scrollview but then move the inset of the scroll indicators. You cannot do that with SwiftUI only but you would need to introspect the underlying `UIScrollView` for that. [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) is good for that.

And then adjust the `verticalScrollIndicatorInsets` to your needs

Comment: Solutions is very helpful, but i tried with nested Lists and its not working, like every tab have a list then how to achieve?